# SQL Group by Style

Tags: sql

So I tried googling this for a definitive answer, but nothing really came up.  Simply put, the question is which of the following is better (assume `A` is a unique id In `T1`):

```
  SELECT T1.A, SUM(T2.B), T1.C, T1.D, ...
    FROM T1
    JOIN T2
      ON T1.A = T2.A
GROUP BY T1.A, T1.C, T1.D, ...
```

OR

```
  SELECT T1.A, SUM(T2.B), MAX(T1.C) AS C, MAX(T1.D) AS D, ...
    FROM T1
    JOIN T2
      ON T1.A = T2.A
GROUP BY T1.A
```

OR

```
  SELECT DISTINCT T1.A, SUM(T2.B) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.A), T1.C, T1.D, ...
    FROM T1
    JOIN T2
      ON T1.A = T2.A
```

Edit: Better in terms of readability and performance.  Obviously number 3 most likely performs poorly.  Readability and maintainability is the main concern.  I personally prefer the first, but there is a fair amount of work in the form of number 2 here at work, and I was wondering if there was a significant difference between the two.

Comment: *Better* in terms of what exactly? Efficiency? Readability? Number of characters typed? What specific RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many questions that ask "which is better" are likely to be a matter of opinion.  For what you want to do, the first or second versions are fine:

```
SELECT T1.A, SUM(T2.B), T1.C, T1.D, ...
FROM T1 JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.A = T2.A
GROUP BY T1.A, T1.C, T1.D, ...
```

Why?

- As written, this is ANSI-SQL compliant and should run in any database.
- The second version (as originally written) would only work in MySQL or, under some circumstances, Postgres (or other databases that support the ANSI concept of functionally independent columns in the `group by` clause).
- The second version is now fine.
- The third version is simply inscrutable for ordinary human beings.  Okay, that's a matter of opinion and I admit it.
- More importantly, the third version hides the intention of the query, which is an aggregation.

The first two points are what make the first version "better".

Note:  an alternative version would use a correlated subquery and might have better performance in many cases:

```
select t1.*,
       (select sum(t2.b) from t2 where t2.A = t1.A) as b
from t1;
```

This version is only equivalent if `t1.A` is unique.

Comment: The second version (now) has aggregate functions on all non-grouped fields, so it should work in all ANSI SQL-compliant databases.